# Getting Null or Blank when displaying data from backend in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The data which is fetched from the backend is displayed as null or a blank
screen. But when I am printing the data in console it printing the data.

Basically, we uploaded an excel file in the backend (Laravel) and now we're trying to show the data in Excel in flutter App but getting null or blank.

Following is the code & exact error details - https://jmp.sh/5mMBILF
(This is the PDF)

Please help.
Thanks